# How can i send an attachment through mail in android app?

Tags: java, android, sendmail, attachment, email-attachments

Hi I am sending a mail through android app. I import the mail library and activation library in my app.

When i send the mail has been sent successfully but the attachment is didn't. Can any tell me how can i send that also.

Here is my code:

```
public synchronized void sendMail(String body, String recipients) throws Exception {   
        try{
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);   
        DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));   
        message.setSender(new InternetAddress("shankar.uclid@gmail.com"));   
        message.setSubject("Request For Claim");


        MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart2=new MimeBodyPart(); // creating new MimeBodyPart object and setting DataHandler to this object
        String filename="file:///android_asset/code.js"; //you can change according to your choice
        DataSource source=new FileDataSource(filename);
        messageBodyPart2.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        messageBodyPart2.setFileName(filename);

        Multipart multipart=new MimeMultipart(); 
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart2);

        message.setContent(multipart);

        message.setDataHandler(handler);  
        showLog("recepetent is "+recipients);
        if (recipients.indexOf(',') < 0)   

            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse("shankar.uclid@gmail.com"));   
        else  
            message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));   
        Transport.send(message);   
        }catch(Exception e){

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I don't why my attachment not getting.

Thank You

Comment: See here http://www.tutorialsbuzz.com/2014/02/send-mail-attachment-android-application.html

Comment: see here  too http://www.androidhub4you.com/2013/09/send-email-with-attachment-in-android.html

Comment: these links are not using mail.jar, activation.jar. I want through code directly not for the any extractions.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
    public static void email(Context context, String to, String cc,String subject, String body, List<String> files)
    {
        //need to "send multiple" to get more than one attachment
        final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
        emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                new String[]{to});
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_CC,
                new String[]{cc});
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
        //has to be an ArrayList
        ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
        //convert from paths to Android friendly Parcelable Uri's
        for (String file : files)
        {
            File fileIn = new File(file);
            Uri u = Uri.fromFile(fileIn);
            uris.add(u);
        }
        emailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
        context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
    }
```

Comment: No Man, I want to attach the file.